# using css gradient to accomplish a fade out

Tags: css, gradient

So using this code

```
#grad1 {
    height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(243,243,243,0), rgba(243,243,243,9)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243,243,243,0), rgba(243,243,243,9)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243,243,243,0), rgba(243,243,243,9)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(243,243,243,0), rgba(243,243,243,9)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

I was able to accomplish a css background gradient to fade out, but I'm just wanting the very bottom to fade.

I have a fixed header and would like it to fade out at the bottom for smoother scrolling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A in RGBA cannot exceed 1...yours is 9.

```css
#grad {
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(243, 243, 243, 0), rgba(243, 243, 243, 1));
}
body {
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0;
  height:750px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```

If you want the gradient to stop just before the bottom of the element, add a color stop.

```css
#grad {
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, 
  rgba(243, 243, 243, 0), 
  rgba(243, 243, 243, 1) 20%,   
  rgba(243, 243, 243, 1));
  border-bottom:1px solid grey; /* for reference only */
}
body {
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0;
  height:750px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```

Comment: Added an example with color stop....otherwise you'll have to provide an image of what it is you want.